# Using base64 function results in InvalidCharacterError

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

What I want to do is using `base-64` module method, in my node.js + express project.

The code is like this.

```
router.get('/list', function(req, res, next) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM Document',function(err, row){
        if(err) throw err;
        var base64 = require('base-64');
        row.forEach(e => {
            e.text = base64.decode(e.text);
        });
        res.render('main/list',{title:"###", row:row});
    })
});
```

In this function, there are MySQL query in the callback.

The `text` is the base-64 encoded value of the Database.

But, the `base64.encode()` doesn't work in this code, but results in `InvalidCharacterError`

how should I use correctly?

Comment: Does not work is not a helpful description. What is the content of `e.text` in the individual rows after the `forEach`  loop and how does this differ from what you expect?

Comment: @t.niese The each row is like this `row : {id:123, date:yyyymmdd, text:(base64 encoded), ...}` and the `forEach` loop is for printing pure decoded text of `row.text`

Comment: My question was what does `text` contain **after** the `forEach`  loop, that gives you the assumption that `decode` did not work?

Comment: @t.niese Actually, The error is `InvalidCharacterError`. I think that the Cause is   `var base64 = require('base-64');` didn't work. And, When I tried to manipulate the `row` object, for example `row[0].text = "pure text"`, it worked. So my expected result is `row : {id:123, date:yyyymmdd, text:(decoded text), ... }` .

Comment: So you get an error message. You have to include such important informations in the question. The problem is not with `var base64 = require('base-64');`  but with the `e.text`  to be decoded.  Write `try { e.text = base64.decode(e.text);  } catch (err ) {console.log('can not decode "' + e.text + '"')}` instead of `e.text = base64.decode(e.text);`  and show what it logs.

Comment: @t.niese I've just find the cause of error. there are plane text which couldn't be decoded in the DB. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nodejs built-in functions

```
let original = 'abcdefrgsdfdsf123123123123';
let testCode64 = Buffer.from(original).toString('base64') 
let testDecode64 = Buffer.from(testCode64, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
```